# Possible to open calendar widget after clicking anywhere in input?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, datepicker

I am working on a React component for a date picker. Specifically, I am trying to open the calendar widget in HTML5 date input whenever someone clicks anywhere inside the input, not just on the arrow icon. My current code is below, but for some reason the calendar won't open unless I click the arrow. I have also tried sending a F4 keyboard event to no avail.

```
class DateInput extends React.Component {
  private input;

  onClick = e => {
    if (this.input) {
      this.input.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
     const { value, onChange } = this.props;

     return (
      <input
        ref={input => (this.input = input)}
        type='date'
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onClick={this.onClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to put a `<View>` component over this input and put `onClick` event on it like code below :

```
class DateInput extends React.Component {
  private input;

  onClick = e => {
    if (this.input) {
      this.input.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
     const { value, onChange } = this.props;

     return (
      <View onClick={this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)}>
      <input
        ref={input => (this.input = input)}
        type='date'
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onClick={this.onClick} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```